# Can any one tell why my Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, drop-down-menu

I am having a drop down binded from the database. On selectedindexchanged of dropdown i will enable some other controls this was working fine when i build my application and running properly. But when i create a virtual folder in the default website of IIS and access the project path for that virtual folder and running Dropdown_selectedInedexChanged event was not firing can any one tell why.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570294/asp-net-c-dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-in-server-control-not-firing

Comment: @Kangkan this was different from you specified i am unable to get the event fire when i create a virtual folder in IIS and running

Comment: Are the rest of the features working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the event handler in the code behind:

```
Protected void Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    //...other code
    ddlMyOne.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlMyOne_SelectedIndexChanged);
    ddlMyOne.AutoPostBack = true;
    //other code...
End Sub 

protected void ddlMyOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your handler code
    }
```

Comment: This was added already in the control event that was not sufficient na

Comment: @Dorababu: So, you have the handler addition in the page_load? Why not publish some of your code segment for people to understand what you have done and tried already?

Comment: I had not add handler but for the control i set Autopostback to true and select the event from Events property is it ok are i have to do as per you said

Comment: So try adding the handler as well.